# Python to convert image links into a file

Tags: python, rest, parse-platform

I need to upload a large amount of data. All contain links to images- but I need them to be uploaded as actual files (via JSON). I'm uploading using the RestAPI into Parse.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/classes/TEST', json.dumps({
       "score": 1337,
       "playerName": "Sean Plott",
       "photo": "http://www.test.com/image.jpg",
     })
results = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print results
```

I'm very new to Python. I believe I need to change the content type? How can I do this on bulk for it to apply to all ".jpg" on within the .json file being uploaded?

## I just thought of another way to do this- I can upload all my data to parse (with links).Then can I use Python (via the RESTAPI) to convert the existing links into files to store in a new column?

Comment: Why not use a wrapper for Parse in python, like this: https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy ?

Comment: I tried this suggestion but I had trouble getting it to interact with Parse. I've installed the files, created the "settings local" with my API keys, then created a .py file with `from parse_rest.connection import register
register(<application_id>, <rest_api_key>[, master_key=None])` to register with Parse. But- I get an invalid syntax error. I tried filling out my API key values (with and without < >) but didnt work. Any suggestion?

Comment: I just thought of another way to do this- I can upload all my data to parse (with links). Can I then use the REST API to simply store those links as files within a collumn in Parse?